# How does Stack Overflow handle duplicate tags in a specific post after merging tags?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

Let's suppose a user posted a question about JavaScript, he/she entered **js** and **javascript** as tags. But later, a moderator merged **js** and **javascript** into one master tag, it's now just **javascript**. Well, the system could simply execute an SQL update to replace the TagId of former **js** into the TagId **javascript** in a Tag Dictionary table, but the problem is, the post will finally have two identical tags (Looks like this `Tags: javascript, javascript`), so I was wondering how does Stack Overflow handle this problem?

I know we could do a big loop for that update, but when a heavy website has tons of posts, the process will be extremely expensive and too long to respond.

Comment: I'm not sure how useful it is to go into detail, but there *is* a de-duplication process here...

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, SO actually *doesn't* handle this, and the exact problem you described will happen: the post will have two identical [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tags

---

**Edit**: I tried it to make sure (I made the tag [test-tag](/questions/tagged/test-tag) on a question that had [proposed-faq](/questions/tagged/proposed-faq) and then merged the former into the latter):

[image: Screenshot of the problem]